# Cake migrations seed not working (Could not infer database type)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

While `my bin/cake bake all` command is working and i get printed all possible model names based on my database to bake, my migrations are not working. This is the error i'm getting it.

```
bin/cake migrations seed

Welcome to CakePHP v3.3.12 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/src/
PHP : 7.1.0
---------------------------------------------------------------
Exception: Could not infer database type from driver in [/Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/ConfigurationTrait.php, line 151]
2017-01-28 12:47:48 Error: [InvalidArgumentException] Could not infer database type from driver
Stack Trace:
#0 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/ConfigurationTrait.php(83): Migrations\Command\Seed->getAdapterName('mysql')
#1 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Console/Command/AbstractCommand.php(91): Migrations\Command\Seed->getConfig()
#2 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/ConfigurationTrait.php(206): Phinx\Console\Command\AbstractCommand->bootstrap(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Command/Seed.php(69): Migrations\Command\Seed->bootstrap(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(262): Migrations\Command\Seed->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(826): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(189): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Migrations\Command\Seed), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(120): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Shell/MigrationsShell.php(101): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 [internal function]: Migrations\Shell\MigrationsShell->main('migrations', 'seed')
#10 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(472): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Shell/MigrationsShell.php(156): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, true, Array)
#12 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(227): Migrations\Shell\MigrationsShell->runCommand(Array, true, Array)
#13 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(182): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->_dispatch(Array)
#14 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(128): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->dispatch(Array)
#15 /Users/myhostcomputer/workspace/myapp/bin/cake.php(34): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#16 {main}
```

This is my datasource configuration from app.php

```
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
            'username' => 'XXXXXXXX',
            'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'database' => 'XXXXXXXX',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'flags' => [],
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'log' => false,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
            //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],

            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
        ],
```

Maybe it has to do something with that i'm working on mac os and i'm using MAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql` is not a valid `driver` option value, this will most likely fail on case-sensitive filesystems, as it will translate to a file called `mysql.php`.

The correct short classname would be `Mysql`, with an uppercase `M`, however the migrations plugin doesn't support short classnames (as can be seen in [**the source where the exception is being thrown**](https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/blob/1.6.7/src/ConfigurationTrait.php#L134)), it expects either (fully) qualified classnames, or constructed driver class instances.

So, long story short:

```
'driver' => \Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql::class
```

Comment: Defining ::class was not necessary, but yes, now is working... Thank you!

Comment: Using the [magic `class` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) should for sure be required (unless you would define the classname as a string of course), removing it should cause a fatal error, as the code would try to access a non-existing, namespaced constant. @Valor_

Comment: that's strange, because its not working with ::class and its working with without ::class... any way it working so thx